# Zend studio error - Exception while removing a file from index

Tags: eclipse, zend-studio

Im using Zend  studio 7.2.1 and when i try to open it I get a message saying that an error occured , i tried Zend Studio 9 but it gives the same error and in the log it says that an exception is  thrown while removing file x from index .

Here's part of the log from my workspace's metadata :

```
!ENTRY org.eclipse.dltk.core.index.sql 4 0 2011-12-08 17:26:30.140
!MESSAGE An exception thrown while removing file '/Project/web/application/Component/FECH/ondomreadycommun.phtml' from index
!STACK 0
org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: General error: java.lang.NullPointerException; SQL statement:
DELETE FROM FILES WHERE PATH=? AND CONTAINER_ID=?; [50000-122]
    at org.h2.message.Message.getSQLException(Message.java:106)
    at org.h2.message.Message.convert(Message.java:283)
    at org.h2.command.Command.executeUpdate(Command.java:229)
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcPreparedStatement.executeUpdateInternal(JdbcPreparedStatement.java:139)
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(JdbcPreparedStatement.java:128)
    at org.eclipse.dltk.internal.core.index.sql.h2.H2FileDao.delete(H2FileDao.java:164)
    at org.eclipse.dltk.internal.core.index.sql.SqlIndexer.removeDocument(SqlIndexer.java:224)
    at org.eclipse.dltk.internal.core.index2.ReconcileSourceModuleRequest.run(ReconcileSourceModuleRequest.java:55)
    at org.eclipse.dltk.core.search.indexing.AbstractJob.execute(AbstractJob.java:77)
    at org.eclipse.dltk.internal.core.search.processing.JobManager.run(JobManager.java:461)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.h2.index.PageDataLeaf.getRowAt(PageDataLeaf.java:300)
    at org.h2.index.PageDataLeaf.getRow(PageDataLeaf.java:412)
    at org.h2.index.PageDataNode.getRow(PageDataNode.java:284)
    at org.h2.index.PageDataIndex.getRow(PageDataIndex.java:361)
    at org.h2.index.PageDataIndex.getRow(PageDataIndex.java:350)
    at org.h2.table.TableData.getRow(TableData.java:116)
    at org.h2.index.PageBtreeIndex.getRow(PageBtreeIndex.java:269)
    at org.h2.index.PageBtreeCursor.get(PageBtreeCursor.java:46)
    at org.h2.index.IndexCursor.get(IndexCursor.java:147)
    at org.h2.table.TableFilter.getValue(TableFilter.java:650)
    at org.h2.expression.ExpressionColumn.getValue(ExpressionColumn.java:168)
    at org.h2.expression.Comparison.getValue(Comparison.java:215)
    at org.h2.expression.ConditionAndOr.getValue(ConditionAndOr.java:86)
    at org.h2.expression.Expression.getBooleanValue(Expression.java:188)
    at org.h2.command.dml.Delete.update(Delete.java:57)
    at org.h2.command.CommandContainer.update(CommandContainer.java:72)
    at org.h2.command.Command.executeUpdate(Command.java:209)
    ... 8 more

......



!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2011-12-15 09:51:22.358
!MESSAGE The following is a complete list of bundles which are not resolved, see the prior log entry for the root cause if it exists:
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2011-12-15 09:51:22.358
!MESSAGE Bundle org.eclipse.jdt.apt.pluggable.core_1.0.201.R35x_v20090818-0225 [341] was not resolved.
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.jdt.apt.pluggable.core 2 0 2011-12-15 09:51:22.358
!MESSAGE Missing imported package org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.tool_0.0.0.
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.jdt.apt.pluggable.core 2 0 2011-12-15 09:51:22.358
!MESSAGE Missing imported package org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.apt.dispatch_0.0.0.
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.jdt.apt.pluggable.core 2 0 2011-12-15 09:51:22.358
!MESSAGE Missing imported package org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.apt.model_0.0.0.
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.jdt.apt.pluggable.core 2 0 2011-12-15 09:51:22.358
!MESSAGE Missing imported package org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.apt.util_0.0.0.
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2011-12-15 09:51:22.358
!MESSAGE Bundle org.eclipse.jdt.compiler.apt_1.0.201.R35x_v20090825-1530 [343] was not resolved.
!SUBENTRY 2 org.eclipse.jdt.compiler.apt 2 0 2011-12-15 09:51:22.358
!MESSAGE Missing imported package org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.tool_0.0.0.
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.osgi 2 0 2011-12-15 09:51:22.358
!MESSAGE Bundle org.eclipse.jdt.compiler.tool_1.0.100.v_972_R35x [344] was not resolved.
```

How can i fix this ?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you reinstall Zend Studio?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just deleted .metadata folder from my workspace then restarted zend studio and it worked .